# Reserving system memory using kernel boot parameters

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, boot

I was playing with some of the linux boot params. I was trying to create a hole in system memory using memmap option. I have a 6GB system and e820 map shows: 0x100000-0xcf49d000 as usable memory. I decided to create a hole from 128MB to 1G and mark it as reserved and allow system to use memory from 1G-2G.

In boot options I configured it as follows:
`memmap=890M$128M memmap=1G@1G`.

However, once system boots up the modified memory map is quite different that what I expect.

`0000000000100000 - 0000000037a00000 (usable)

 0000000040000000 - 0000000080000000 (usable)`

What I must be doing wrong?

I do know, kernel needs some low memory and I cant completely make a whole from 1M to 1G. That is why I thought of giving 128MB for initial boot sequence.

Thanks

Comment: Try adding the mem= option so the kernel is mlimited to the total amount you want to use.

Comment: tried and does not seem to work.

Comment: @agent.smith This is not the best option, but have you tried marking that region as 'bad memory' (BadRAM)?  Also try using the a hexadecimal address as the start of memory location with memmap=.